# how to compare today date to given date

Tags: jsp

i want to compare to current date to given date in database just i want to test with this code but this is always showing false if current date equals to given date

```
<%
   Date now = new Date();
   DateFormat df  =new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
  String date= String.valueOf(df.format(now));
  out.println(date);
   if(date=="12/03/2014")
 {
 out.println("true");
 }
  else
 {
    out.println("false");
  }

 %>
```

this is my real code : Actually  i want to check if taken leave date match with current date then subtract from total working day  please help me. how to do

```
   <%
       String mon=session.getAttribute("str1").toString();// mon,tue,... is given date in database
       String tue=session.getAttribute("str2").toString();
       String wed=session.getAttribute("str3").toString();
       String thr=session.getAttribute("str4").toString(); 
       String fri=session.getAttribute("str5").toString();
        Date now =new Date();
        DateFormat df =new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String changedate= String.valueOf(df.format(now));
       if( changedate== mon || changedate==tue || changedate==wed || changedate==thr || changedate==fri)
         {
           // "a" is total number of taken leave by employee like 1,2,3... days 
           String a=session.getAttribute("str16").toString();
            int y=Integer.parseInt(a);
           }
           else{
           //  i am not getting any idea if employee did not take any leave then subtract 0 from total working day
               }


   %>
     here display actual working day  
    <td><%= totalworkingday-y %>
```

Answer (score 0):

`if(date=="12/03/2014")` will not work

use `if(date.equals("12/03/2014"))`

When you use == it compares if both the objects are same. Here date and "12/03/2014" are two different `String` objects. You will always get false.

To compare the value of the object you need to use `.equals`.

Note: For custom objects you need to over rite equals method to use it.